# How to have horizontal stacked group plots and how to remove spaces between bars?

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

I have code like this:

```
    data <- read.csv("test1.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)

# Graph
myplot=ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=condition)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#7b3294", "#c2a5cf", "#a6dba0", "#008837"))+
    ylab("Performance (ns/day)") +
    facet_wrap(~specie,nrow=3, labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85), strip.position="bottom") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "mm"),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5))



myplot + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), legend.title=element_blank(), 
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0.5))
```

And my data is this:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(specie = c("gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s benchMEM.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000", 
"gmx mdrun -gpu_id 1 -ntomp 16 -s MD_15NM_WATER.tpr -nsteps 10000"
), condition = c("Tesla P100-SYCL", "Tesla V100-SYCL", "Tesla P100-CUDA", 
"Tesla V100-CUDA", "Tesla P100-SYCL", "Tesla V100-SYCL", "Tesla P100-CUDA", 
"Tesla V100-CUDA"), value = c(75.8, 77.771, 63.297, 78.046, 34.666, 
50.052, 32.07, 59.815)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

How do I:

1. have these two plots next to each other, not on the top of each other
2. How do I remove spaces between those bars?

[image]

Comment: are you using `myplot` or `facet_plot`? Or are they the same thing?

Comment: sorry it was a type I edited it now

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with this code:

```
facet_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = condition, y = value, fill = condition)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width=1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ specie, switch="both", labeller = label_wrap_gen(width = 85)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#7b3294", "#c2a5cf", "#a6dba0", "#008837"))+
      ylab("Performance (ns/day) ") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        legend.title=element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill="gray", colour="black", size=1),
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold", size=rel(1.2)))

# Call facet plot:

facet_plot + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), limits = c(0, 80))
```